# Stars fade out after click in Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to make a star-rating component in Vue.js and the problem now is that after I click the stars, it fades out before showing the final result. Below is the JSFiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/L6L34ybr/5/

which is different from the effect where I've mostly copied the code:

http://codepen.io/nouveller/pen/qOxKBJ

I guess it has something to do with the `rating` property.

And now I've bind the class inline `:class="{selected: ((value >= rating && value != null))}`.

But I want to bind it with a Object like `:class="selected: someFunction(rating)"`
and then write the `someFunction(rating)` in the computed property or somewhere else not in the html. Is there someway to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
@click="setRate(rating)"
```

define your click event like so:

```
@click.prevent="setRate(rating)"
```

This will stop the click event from the cause of the problem, which is that it's firing twice, once for the label and once for the input.

As for your second question, you can add your `someFunction()` in your component's `methods` object like this:

```
methods: {
    someFunction: function (value, rating) {
        return value >= rating && value != null;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in your markup as follows:

```
<label :class="{selected: someFunction(value, rating)}">
```

Comment: But why firing twice would make it fade? It seems twice would have the same result as once.

Comment: The underlying problem is a conflict with the `value` property because it is being manually modified in `setRate()` but upon clicking the `<label>` the radio `<input>` selection causes the `value` property to change as well.

Comment: I thought the radios have the values of 1,2,3,4,5 and didn't verify that (which is why I thought triggering them would set the `value` prop to the right value of 1,2,3,4,5). Turns out their values are not set and the default value is `"on"`, which is `NaN` when converted to number, thus `(value >= rating && value != null)` is always false, so the stars faded out...